On commutator of bounded operators
Let $\mathbb H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\mathcal B(\mathbb H)$ be the bounded operators on
$\mathbb H$. Let $J,K\in  \mathcal B(\mathbb H)$ such that
$
J=J^*, K=-K^*.
$
Then the commutator $[J,K]$ is selfadjoint, equal to $JK+(JK)^*$.
Claim. If $[J,K]\ge 0$, then $[J,K]=0$.
Question. Is it true, is it well-known? What I know is that it is impossible to have $[J,K]=I$, showing that Quantum Mechanics needs unbounded operators to get the Uncertainty Principle, based upon the non-commutation of operators such as $D_x=\frac1{i}\frac{d}{dx}=J$ and $ix=K$. Here, we have a stronger statement, claiming that it is not even possible that the spectrum of the self-adjoint bounded operator $[J,K]$ is included in the non-negative half-line. (I guess that the above Claim also prevents the spectrum to be included in the non-positive half-line.)

If one of the operators is trace class, it follows immediately from the fact that the trace of $[J,K]$ (or any commutator) vanishes. It shouldn't be hard to get the general case by approximation.

More generally, the claim is easy if one of $J$ or $K$ has a basis of eigenvectors. Indeed, if $\xi$ is an eigenvector for $J$ or $K$, then $\langle [J,K] \xi,\xi\rangle=0$. The approximation argument does not seem straighforward to me, though.

If $H$ is finite dimensional there is a one-line solution: ${\rm tr}(JK - KJ) = 0$, so $JK - KJ$ cannot have positive spectrum.
But it is false in general! Let $V$ be a partial isometry from $H$ onto a proper subspace $H_0$, so that $V^*V = I$ and $VV^* = P \neq I$ is the projection onto $H_0$. Then let $J = V + V^*$ and $K = V - V^*$; we have $[J,K] = 2(V^*V - VV^*) = 2(I - P) \geq 0$, but it is not zero.

Nice example, Nik.

@MikaeldelaSalle thank you!

Nice! The shift operator has struck again...

Sharp and natural: a great example. Thx.
